# Problem to use `\cite`

Tags: bibtex, citing, miktex

[image]

As you can see, I entered `\usepackage{cite}`, then made a `bib` file `citations.bib`. The entered syntax for citing `\cite{}` and then closed The syntax with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `bibliography{citations}`.

Both the `.tex` and `.bib` file are in the same directory. I compiled the file with `pdflatex` first, then `bibtex` and then again with `pdflatex`, but still to no avail.

Comment: How you inserted the bibliography data in the `bib` file? The name you give there should be the same you use inside `\cite{}` (that is, `norgate`).

Comment: You mention that you ran LaTeX *once* after running BibTeX. However, after running BibTeX, it's necessary to run LaTeX *twice more* to update the citation call-outs correctly.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't ever post images of code. Instead, copy and paste your code as text into your question.

Comment: @Mico, well observed. I edited and supposing it was a typo, I typed `pdflatex` there. Should I revert it?

Comment: @Sigur - Your edit is fine. Let's wait and see if the OP responds.

Comment: "\nofiles" was in my code. So no .aux files were created, thus compiler never read the .bib file. @cfr, point duly noted. Thanks mico and sigur.

Comment: @KAdityaVikram Do you want to answer the question yourself or should we close this?

Comment: Yes i will answer my own question. Thank you cfr.

Answer (score 1):

There is "\nofiles" in the code. This stops creating .aux files. Which in turn does not allow the compiler to read bibtex file. That is the problem. Thus for referencing(bibliography) \nofiles should not be there in the code.